# How do I set the date with Apples's `xcrun simctl status_bar`

Tags: xcode, command-line, xcode11

With Apple's new command line tool `xcrun simctl status_bar` you can now set up the status bar in the simulator as you like without any need for 3rd party programs, however, I can't get it to change the date for bigger devices like the iPad Pro (12.9-inch).

In the help menu it states that if you enter a valid ISO date then it adapts that on devices where this is relevant:
[xcrun simctl status_bar --help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFwyY.png)

So I enter a valid ISO date `2016-09-18T17:34:02.666Z`, but the status bar will afterwards look like this:
[date not correctly changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQo2R.png)

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid the milliseconds and the `Z` timezone do not work, you should use this format:

```
xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "2007-01-09T09:41:00+01:00"
```

Comment: Don't know why, but this resets the date to the English timezone. Is there a possibility to use the time zone currently set in the iPad simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't very precise for this particular feature.

Try `xcrun simctl status_bar <device> override --time "10:22"` and it'll work.

Comment: Yeah the documentation really sucks unfortunately. Wouldn't that simply set the time to `10:22`, but not change the date at all?

Comment: That's right, this just adjusts the displayed time in the status bar. As per my understanding, `xcrun simctl status_bar` isn't meant  be used for adjustments of internal settings like a date. It's just there to make the status bar look as desired to simplify screenshot-taking etc.

Comment: I'm think you're right. It just really confused me because as you can see in my first screenshot it says that it can adjust the date as well on relevant devices, which would be the newer iPad as they also display the date.